# Mocking proto.Message in Go

Tags: unit-testing, go, proto

I wrote a function that takes a list of `proto.Message` objects. Looking at the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf@v1.28.0/proto#Message), it seems like `proto.Message` wraps `protoreflect.ProtoMessage` which contains a single function, `ProtoReflect() Message`. Looking at the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf@v1.28.0/reflect/protoreflect#Message) for `Message`, it implements a number of other functions that return types referenced by the `protoreflect` package.

It seems that attempting to create a mock `proto.Message` would be a lot more work that it's worth but I don't want to go through the whole process of creating a protobuf file, compiling it and referencing it just for unit testing.

Is there another way I can create a mock `proto.Message` object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into this further, I decided that the best thing to do would be to create an actual protobuf message:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package my.package;

option go_package = "path/to/my/package"; // golang

message TestRecord {
    string key = 1;
    string value = 2;
}
```

and compile it into a Golang file and then modify it for my own purposes:

```
$ protoc --go_out=./gopb/ --go_opt=paths=source_relative *.proto
```

Once the test file has been created, I can delete it or save it as a record.